Suddenly mouse and touchpad does not work in Ubuntu 20.04
I have an Lenovo LOQ 15 laptop and my native OS is Ubuntu 20.04 when I work with laptop suddenly my left click in touchpad and mouse it's doesn't work, the scroll in touchpad and right. Click in mouse is OK, but I can't use left click. I tried common approaches and solutions in the internet, but nothing changed.
Just when I restart the laptop everything goes OK, but I don't want to restart my laptop every time for this small thing. I know it's not a hardware issue, because I had Windows 11 on this laptop before and I didn't encounter this problem at all.
